# finding last saved id using NHibernate LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate

Currently I'm using following code

```
 var lastId = DataRepository.All().ToList().LastOrDefault().Id;
```

in order to find last inserted row `Id`

How can I refactor above code without projecting into `ToList()`?

`DataRepository.All()` returns `IQuerable<T>`

Comment: What is the data type of 'Id'? If Id increases when new rows are inserted, you could use `DataRepository.All().Max(x => x.Id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really as easy as a [HashPsi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169124/finding-last-saved-id-using-nhibernate-linq#comment-54147576) comment.

In case that your `DataRepository.All()` returns `IQuerable<T>` -  all these kinds of queries will result in one simple SQL statement returning just the last **Id**:

```
// query
IQueryable<T> query = DataRepository.All();

// just MAX
var maxIdA = query
   .Max(x => x.Id);

// also this kind of construct with Take() and SingleOrDefault()
// will be effective (not loading complete list from DB to app)
// and could be used for more complex queries with unique result
var maxIdB = query
      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
      .Select(x => x.Id)
      .Take(1)
      .SingleOrDefault();
```